# GSM noise on lm35

Tags: stm32, gsm, noise, adc, sim800

i use lm35 temperature sensor and stm32 f030k6 for reading sensor output
when i call sim800 , lm35 output is noisy and incorrect value and When I open the antenna, the noise disappears.
How can I remove this noise?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can help other users to answer your question with a code example showing how to reproduce the issue you are experiencing. Further info about how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sounds like you may need some filtering, can you share a schematic?